# SQL selecting when condition is satisfied

Tags: sql, select

I have two SQL questions that I can not figure out.

1) selecting 'first_name' and 'last_name' if a student is an 'age' of 10 and has 100 on the 'score' from 'student'

2) I have create the procedure named 'get_student_name' that will take the student ID as a parameter and return the name of students

For number #1, I think...

```
Select Student.first_name, Student.last_name
when age = 10 and score = 100
from Student
```

but it is not working.

For number #2, TBH, I have no idea what the question is asking for..

I will appreciate if some can help me out here.

Thank you so much guys

Comment: which database are you using? oracle / mysql/mssql

Comment: I am using mysql

Answer (score 0):

For the answer on your #1 why does it not work, instead of **WHEN**, you should use **WHERE**. Then you can remove **Student** from **FirstName and LastName** query because SQL already knew where you will be getting that fields at.

I think the answer for your question #2 would be creating a stored procedure with this information:

```
@StudentID int

SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Student WHERE StudentID = @StudentID
```

Where @StudentID = Value from a textbox or combobox from your interface or a value from your Table Student

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Query syntax is not right. Try

```
Select first_name, last_name    
    from Student
WHERE age = 10 and score = 100
```

And for the 2nd part

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_student_name
(
   studentID varchar(50)
) 
BEGIN 
  SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Student WHERE StudentID = @StudentID
END;
```

Comment: Did you **try** your answer for the second part?